# PHP - Show Array value

Tags: php, arrays

i have a little problem how to show the array values of this script.
It scans after filenames with string "tn" inside a dir  and gives out a array.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "pics/tn_2.jpg" [1]=> string(13) "pics/tn_1.jpg" }
```

I need to know how i can just show one value for example echo array[0]

thats the entire code:

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 $searchDir = 'pics/';
 $searchExtList = array('.jpg');
 $searchString = 'tn';

 $allFiles = everythingFrom($searchDir,$searchExtList,$searchString);

 var_dump($allFiles);

function everythingFrom($baseDir,$extList,$searchStr) {
 $ob = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($baseDir),     RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($ob as $name => $object){
    if (is_file($name)) {
        foreach($extList as $k => $ext) {
            if (substr($name,(strlen($ext) * -1)) == $ext) {
                $tmp = file_get_contents($name);
                if (strpos($tmp,$searchStr) !== false) {
                    $files[] = $name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return $files;

}

echo $files['0']; // doesnt works !!!!!!!!!!!
  ?>
```

Comment: you need an integer as key, remove the quotes

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code and will be of no use to future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$allFiles = everythingFrom($searchDir,$searchExtList,$searchString);
echo $allFile[0];
```

Comment: Hi thx for reply but i got with this still an empty page. Oh i deleted a } thanks for your help now it works =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$allFiles = everythingFrom($searchDir,$searchExtList,$searchString);
```

now your $allFiles array look like this:

```
{ [0]=> string(13) "pics/tn_2.jpg" [1]=> string(13) "pics/tn_1.jpg" }
```

to get data from [0] write this:

```
echo $allFiles[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare $files as an array first. Example:

```
function everythingFrom($baseDir,$extList,$searchStr) {
    $files = array();
    ....
```